# SSIS Setting the HasSideEffects property

Tags: ssis

I am calling a stored procedure in a data flow task that outputs a value that is not being used.  Because its not being used the optimizer removes the component during runtime.  It states I can override this by setting the 'HasSideEffects' property to true but I don't see where to set this.  I see it in the 'Input and Ouput Properties' of the OLE DB Source but its read only.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had set the 'RunInOptimizedMode' property to true and that was causing the issues.  Set it to false and I am good to go

Comment: I'm here in 2023 having the same issue without any solution. 'RunInOptimizedMode' is already false and  'HasSideEffects' is read-only (right click transformation --> show advanced editor --> Input and output properties --> lookup input). Working fine in visual studio but getting this warning and doesn't work in SQL Server. In a forum someone suggested to set it to true by editing dtsx. That doesn't work, can't even see this property and if I add the it breaks the package.

Comment: @VirajA for a custom component at least, `hasSideEffects="true"` is an attribute of the `<input ...>` element (just inside the `<inputs>` element).  The new attribute sits between the `refId` and `name` attributes.